# How to control the scroll bar dynamically using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Example:I have entered the zipcode by that i found list of stores and when i select the 10th record and submit the form .if again i return to that form it should fetch the details with scroll bar postion.

clarification:everything was done but i m unable to control the scroll bar

```
        $("#search").click(function(){
            var zipCode = $("#zipcodeSearch").val();
            if(zipCode.length){
                $.ajax({
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $(".stores").html("Loading...");
                    }
                    , type: "post"
                    , cache: false
                    , url: '/localstores/?ajax=1&view=radioView'
                    , data: 'zipCode=' + zipCode 
                    , success: function(response){
                        $(".stores").html(response).removeClass("error");

                        //Checking previously selected store
                        if(typeof(selectedStore_ID) != 'undefined' && selectedStore_ID != 0){
                            $("#" + selectedStore_ID).click();
                            $("#" + selectedStore_ID).offset();
                        }else{

                            //Select the first local store by default
                            $("[name=localStore]").eq(0).click();
                        }
                    }
                    , error: function(error){
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                    , complete: function(){
                        if($(".stores").html() == "loading..."){
                            $(".stores").empty();
                        }
                    }
                })
            }else{
                $(".stores").addClass("error").empty().html("Please enter a postcode first.");
            }
        });

        //On click of radio items, showing the item as selected
        $(".stores").delegate("[name=localStore]","click", function(){
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            $("#selectedStore").html($(this).parent("td").next("td").children("label").html());
            $("#selectedStoreId").val(id);
        });
});
```

Thanks,Naresh

Comment: Looks off-topic: `Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)`

Comment: Please clarify and post some code. Its not clear if you are talking about a table of records or a select box list (or something else entirely)

Answer (score 0):

You could save scrollbar position somewhere. (In database, session, cookies, etc.)

Comment: Here is the answer for my question? var elementIndex = $("#" + selectedStore_ID).parent().parent().index();
var unitHight = 690;
var heightToBeScrolled = elementIndex*unitHight;
$(".store-area-sec").eq(1).animate({scrollTop: ($("#3").parent().parent().offset().top - heightToBeScrolled)},'normal');